# How should I improve boggy soil where a pond used to be?

Tags: soil, drainage

I have just filled in a large pond.I Drained the pond and removed the liner. I used bricks and stones to line the bottom and the bought 4 tons of top soil and a ton of soil improver and rotted horse manure.After all this had work and cost the recent rain has created a muddy bog in the pond hole, what can I do to make this fit for planting.

Comment: Removing the bricks and stones that you used to line the hole would be a good start. Normal earth is "soil all the way down" till you get to the solid bedrock.

Comment: Agree - not sure why you lined with bricks and stones, but you've unfortunately created a poor draining mud pit by doing that, you'd have been better to fill in with topsoil and your organic soil improvers on their own.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that adding the hard core would provide extra drainage, as the bottom of the pond looked like clay. Looks like I have a lot more hard work ahead of me to sort out the problem, it’s a ‘big’ pond!

Comment: Thanks again I am considering my options as I cannot do anything until this rain finally stops (if it ever does).

Comment: Oh and of course I meant ‘boggy’ soil (typo!)

Comment: Words I have learned on this site: drywell, french drain. I don't remember where I learned about the Soil Test: 1. get a glass jar 2. fill with water halfway(so the jar is 2/3 full) 3. fill with soil halfway 4. shake hard 5. wait for about an hour. The clay-ness of the soil becomes apparent.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution to hauling it all out may be to make a raised bed there.  The bottom will likely remain a water reservoir.

From your descriptions I suspect that the location was always boggy, and a previous owner made a virtue out of a necessity and put in a pond.

A raised bed either formal (plank or  concrete block) or informal (rocks, logs) will allow the ex-pond to be the drain for the raised bed.  I would suggest at least a foot elevation.

Comment: I have heard more than one story of someone building a pond in a low muddy area in a yard ,sort of two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make virtue out of necessity and plant a bog/damp garden? You could do worse than having a look at Beth Chatto's book *Beth Chatto's Damp Garden: Moisture-Loving Plants for Year-Round Interest* - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Beth-Chattos-Damp-Garden-Moisture-Loving/dp/1844030458. Here's a couple of RHS links for bog gardens: https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=356 and https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=807